# Email attachment not sending with email

Tags: .net, vb.net, scada

Been searching the Forums and while this question has been asked and answered my specific problem isn't among the fixes sadly.

I am working in a SCADA system so System.Web.Mail. commands are all I have available to use.

' are remarked out lines that I have tried already.

Here is what I have the mail sends fine but no attachment;

```
Dim Day as System.dateTime;
Dim sDay as String;
'Dim attachment as System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment;
'Dim attachment as string;

Day = new system.dateTime();
Day = now();
Day = system.dateTime.Parse(Day).AddDays(-1);
sDay = Day.day;

System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.mdu.com";
System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment("G:\Test\" + me.IGCFilename + sday + ".txt");

'System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment attachment = new System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment("G:\Test\" + 
 me.IGCFilename + sday + ".txt");

System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send
(
{from: } "DoNotReply@cngc.com;",
{to: } me.EmailTo,
{subject: } "Daily Gate Volumes sent to Williams",
{body: } "Gas Day Volumes"
);

me.EmailFileNow = false;
```

Comment: Where are you adding the attachment to the email?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an attachment to email using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034503/adding-an-attachment-to-email-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I believe the second system.web,,, should be adding attachment.

Comment: I did try that post but it is using system.net.mail and my SCADA system did not uderstand it,

Comment: Why is this question tagged with C#?

Comment: You appear to have Visual Basic syntax, not C#.  Also you should not be on the mail library but rather the message.  You should have a `MailMessage` that you are using to define your from, to, subject, body, and additional content.

Comment: As far as the programming language I was always told it was a hybrid of C# and VB if that is not correct I do apologize. The majority of the code we right is for control systems so mostly if then else statements.

Comment: @Greg I do apologize I'm not a coder so I'm not sure what you mean by mail library versus message.

Comment: It means that you should be creating a message using the mail library.  If you look at the example in the question in the link I posted above, you will see how your code should look (if you're writing c#, and if you're not, you can easily use an online translator to convert it to VB).  Also, it's possible that you have both VB and c# scripts implemented in your system, but it won't be in the same code block.

Comment: Why is this question tagged VBScript?

Comment: @devlin carnate Thank you for the response but again my system is a dumb scada system that does not understand commands like var, const, System.Net.Mail, that are in the linked post. I have tried modifying the linked post to make it work I have tried running it through only converter tools only to end up with multiple errors. The code I provided is what I could figure out using trial and error and it does work as far as sending the email, just not the attachment. I do not know maybe it cannot send attachments but one of the functions it says it has available is System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment.

Comment: If your doing this in PowerShell lookup how to do mail in PowerShell with C#.

Comment: I have a hunch this is really what you want, PowerShell.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997303/how-to-attach-a-file-to-an-email-with-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code is using the Send(String, String, String, String) method which sends a from, to, subject, body message.

To add a full email with attachments and all try:

```
Dim Day as System.dateTime;
Dim sDay as String;

Day = new system.dateTime();
Day = now();
Day = system.dateTime.Parse(Day).AddDays(-1);
sDay = Day.day;

MailAttachment att = System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment("G:\Test\" + me.IGCFilename + sday + ".txt");

emailMessage = new MailMessage();
emailMessage.From = "DoNotReply@cngc.com;";
emailMessage.To = "me.EmailTo";
emailMessage.Subject = "Daily Gate Volumes sent to Williams";
emailMessage.Body = "Gas Day Volumes";
emailMessage.Attachments.Add(att);

System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.mdu.com";
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(emailMessage);

me.EmailFileNow = false;
```

Without having a vb SCADA system I can't test it but the above code is .net SmtpMail code.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am attempting to get it to work but it is currently throwing an error during check that says first att is not expected.

Comment: Can you post the full error? It is easier to understand what is going wrong with the actual error info.

Comment: With out any further feedback from you @BrianS we cannot help you solve this problem. If my response helped you solve your issue please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: It is still not working. As far as errors they are simply What I posted att not expected. in the code you provided. The errors are not robust enough to work out the issue so I have given up for now as we are in the middle of a SCADA upgrade and I'm focusing on that. This will be needed in the new system but for now it's low priority. I have tried Dim att as a string as a system variable as an attachment variable all with no success.