Find files in folder with specific size, attach files to email
I am trying to create script which will check source folder if it is empty and if it matches size. Then it will find files with specific string in those folders and then it will send those files to specific recipients and then it will move those files with their parent folders to different destination.
So far I have this:
$logDate = get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd
$log = "\\source\log\$logdate.log"

$mailkomu = "SSS@email.com"
$mailod = "DDD@email.com"
$subject = "A100 files"
$zprava = "Text"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.server"
 
$destination = "\\destination\"
$source = "\\source\"
$path = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -File
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory -Recurse
 
$PC1 = "A100"
 
# checks if the source folder is empty
If ((Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Force | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Output "$source - ok - no files" | Out-File $log -Append 
     }
Else {
    foreach ($folder in $folders) {

        # checks, if the folder size is greater than 15 MB
        $size = (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
        $sizeInMB = $size / 1MB
            if ($sizeinMB -gt 15) {
            Write-Output $folder "Folder size is greater than 15 MB" | Out-File $log -Append 
            }

            # the bottom part does not work if there is folder size check
            Else {foreach ($file in $folder){
                $SplitArray = $file.Name.Split("_")
                    foreach ($Splitfile in $SplitArray) {
                        if ($Splitfile -match $PC1) {
                            Write-Output $file | Out-File $log -Append

                            # This part is not working, I don't know how to attach files from $file to email
                            Send-MailMessage -From $mailod -To $email -Subject $subject -Body $zprava -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $file

                            # This part will not move parent folders and files in $file
                            Move-Item -path $file.FullName -destination $destination
                            }
                   }
            }
                     
        }
    }
}

The source destination and files look like this:
\\source\A\XXX_A100_YYY.pdf
\\source\B\ZZZ_A100_FFF.pdf
\\source\C\XXX_A300_YYY.pdf
\\source\D\XXX_A200_YYY.csv
\\source\E\XXX_A300_YYY.pdf
\\source\F\XXX_A100_YYY.pdf

A, B, C,...  - these folders will always have different names. Same for files, only the string will always be somewhere in the name.
The check if source is empty works correctly.
Folder size check works correctly.

Quenstion -
At this moment, I do not know how to load files in folders which don't have size greater than 15MB, so the rest of the code does not work.

If there is not folder size check, the split-array correctly split the file names. And it will find match correctly.

and 3. Question -
How to attach files which match the string in split array to email and then move them with their parent folder to different destination.

It should look like this after the moving.

\\destination\A\XXX_A100_YYY.pdf
\\destination\B\ZZZ_A100_FFF.pdf
\\destination\F\XXX_A100_YYY.pdf

Can you please help me?
Edit
I edited the script and it is moving files with their folders correctly now. The attaching files to the email is still problem. It still attaches one file per one email, not all files to one email.
If ((Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Force | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Output "$source - ok - no files" | Out-File $log -Append 
     }
Else {
    foreach ($folder in $folders) {

        # checks, if the folder size is greater than 15 MB
        $size = (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
        $sizeInMB = $size / 1MB
            if ($sizeinMB -gt 15) {
            Write-Output $folder "Folder size is greater than 15 MB" | Out-File $log -Append 
            continue
                }
        Else {
            Write-Output "folder is not empty"               
            $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName
            foreach ($file in $files) {
            $SplitArray = $file.Name.Split("_")
                foreach ($Splitfile in $SplitArray) {
                    if ($Splitfile -match $PC1) {
                        $attach = @(Get-ChildItem $file.fullname)
                        Write-Output $file
                        Send-MailMessage -From $mailod -To $mailkomu -Subject $subject -Body $zprava -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $attach
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
 
Start-Sleep -seconds 5
 
If($source.Count -eq 0){
    }
Else {
    foreach($folder in $folders) {
            Write-Output "folder moved"
            # this part is for logging purpose
            $data = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.fullname | Select-Object DirectoryName, Name 
            move-item -path $folder.fullname -destination $destination
            Write-Output "Complete"
            }
}


You can test if empty by using if($folders.Count -eq 0)

You can use "Continue" to get next foreach item when size is larger than 15MB

See following for attaching file to email : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997303/how-to-attach-a-file-to-an-email-with-powershell

Use Move-Item for moving files : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7.4

I put "continue" and tried move-item, but there are still some problems which I dont know how to solve.

How many emails are you sending?  Looks like each folder is sent in a separate email.

It is not. If there is 5 files in folder, it will send 5 emails. File per email.

I edited the script and moving files is perfect. But i do not know how to put all files to one email.

See attachments.  It is an array of file names : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.4

I figured it out. The problem was in $attach - this is the correct one $attach = Get-ChildItem $files.fullname And I put send-mail to the end and it works perfectly. I put complete skript to the answer. Thank you for guidance jdweng.

The is the final script. It checks folders if they are empty. If not it checks if they are not larger than 15 MB. If they are not, it will check files based on the specific string. If it will find it, it will send them to the recipient. Then it will wait 5s and move those file to the destination.
$logDate = get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd
$log = "\\source\log\$logdate.log"

$mailkomu = "SSS@email.com"
$mailod = "DDD@email.com"
$subject = "A100 files"
$zprava = "Text"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.server"
 
$destination = "\\destination\"
$destination2 = "\\destination2\"
$source = "\\source\"
$path = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -File
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Directory -Recurse
 
$PC1 = "A100"

$chyby = $false
# checks if the source folder is empty
If ((Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Force | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) {
        Write-Output "$source - ok - no files" | Out-File $log -Append 
     }
Else {
    foreach ($folder in $folders) {

        # checks, if the folder size is greater than 15 MB
        $size = (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -File -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
        $sizeInMB = $size / 1MB
            if ($sizeinMB -gt 15) {
            Write-Output $folder "Folder size is greater than 15 MB" | Out-File $log -Append 
                    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.fullname -File
            foreach ($file in $files) {
            $SplitArray = $file.Name.Split("_")
                foreach ($Splitfile in $SplitArray) {
                    if ($Splitfile -match $PC1) {
                    $chyby = $true
                                    }
                                }
                           }
                     }
        Else {
            Write-Output "folder is not empty"               
            $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName
            foreach ($file in $files) {
            $SplitArray = $file.Name.Split("_")
                foreach ($Splitfile in $SplitArray) {
                    if ($Splitfile -match $PC1) {
                        $attach = Get-ChildItem $files.fullname
                        Write-Output $file
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

if($chyby){
    Send-MailMessage -From $mailod -To $mailkomu -Subject $subject -Body $zprava -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $log
    copy-item -path $folder.fullname -destination $desitnation2 -recurse
    Write-Output "$logtime - files larger than 15 MB copied to destination2" | Out-File $logiskn -Append
    }

Send-MailMessage -From $mailod -To $mailkomu -Subject $subject -Body $zprava -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $attach
 
Start-Sleep -seconds 5
 
If($source.Count -eq 0){
    }
Else {
    foreach($folder in $folders) {
            Write-Output "folder moved"
            # this part is for logging purpose
            $data = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.fullname | Select-Object DirectoryName, Name 
            move-item -path $folder.fullname -destination $destination
            Write-Output "Complete"
            }
}

